# Selecting rows based on grepl results in multiple columns in R

Tags: r, subset, sapply, grepl

I have data (df) like this with 50 diagnosis codes (dx.1 through dx.50) per patient:

```
ID     dx.1     dx.2    dx.50
 1   150200   140650   250400
 2   752802   851812       NA
 3   441402   450220       NA
 4   853406   853200   150404
 5   250604       NA       NA
```

I would like to select the rows that have any of the diagnosis codes starting with "250". So in the example, it would be ID 1 and 5.

After stumbling around for awhile, I finally came up with this:

```
df$select = rowSums(sapply(df[,2:ncol(df)], function(x) grepl("\\<250", x)))
selected = df[df$select>0,]
```

It's kind of clanky and takes a while since I'm running it on several thousand rows.

1. Is there a better/faster way to do this?
2. Is there an easy way to extend this to multiple search criteria?

Comment: If you are working with numbers, don't use regex and convert them to characters.  Try something like `rowSums(df[-1] %/% 1e3 == 250, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Considering multiple search criteria, just use grepl("pattern1|pattern2|etc...", x)

Comment: @David: the diagnosis codes are numbers stored as characters (basically factors).

Comment: @Aleksandr: I didn't know the logic operators would work within the grepl search pattern. Good to know.

Comment: Then I would still try avoiding regex, perhaps something like `rowSums(sapply(df[-1], substr, 1, 3) == "250", na.rm = TRUE)` would be faster?

Comment: You should also make your example reproducible.